# MySQL: Trigger that'll increment a columns value, based on DELETE and INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, insert, sql-delete

I'm wanting to setup a trigger that'll increment a columns value. If I do an INSERT I want it to + 1, and if I do a DELETE I want it to -1.

```
INSERT INTO `users saved` SET `userid` = '$user->id', `topicid` = '$topicid'
DELETE FROM `users saved` WHERE `userid` = '$user->id' AND `topicid` = '$topicid' LIMIT 1
```

DB Schema

```
`users saved`
id | userid | topicid

`total`
topicid | value
```

The table I want the trigger to effect is `total`, I want the value column (int) to go up or down.

I'm quite unsure where to start.

Comment: Why not just do this when you query the table?

Comment: Your approach is less reliable than simply calculating the aggregates on the join on-the-fly.  What would you do if `UPDATE` on the  `total` table fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work although I did not test it, the statement for delete is very similar:

```
CREATE TRIGGER increment_value_on_insert 
    AFTER INSERT ON `users saved`
    REFERENCING
        NEW ROW as new_row
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE total
    SET value = value+1
    WHERE
     topicid = new_row.topicid
    END
```